# PHP-GD installed but required during the wordpress installation

Tags: php, php-gd

I try to install Wordpress using Virtualmin manager. During the installation the manager return:
`Error: Unable to find a match: php74-gd`
after command: `/bin/dnf -y install php74-gd`

I have PHP 7.4 and see module `gd` in modules list.
Anyone know what is the problem?

Comment: Maybe you dont have truetrype installed.

Comment: What does it mean?